# Put similar rows in numpy matrix closed together

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix like this:

```
I = np.eye(3)
I = np.concatenate([I] * 3)
I

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

And I need to organize the matrix like bellow, how can I do it in numpy?

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

I try to use `np.sort()`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) would sort the columns independently, you need to use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) and use the output to reorder the rows:

```
out = I[np.lexsort(I.T)]
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

You can also combine [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
idx, num = np.unique(I, axis=0, return_counts=True)

out = np.repeat(idx, num, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm it works on my problem.